# 404 Response in Google Buzz API

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, google-api, google-buzz

I'm playing around with Google Buzz API from Python,

During the OAuth process when I reach the part of authorizing the token from browser, I go to this URL `https://www.google.com/buzz/api/auth/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token=...`, and when I press `OK, continue` I expect to be directed to a page like this one http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/images/OauthUX_nocallback.png but instead I get a `404 Not Found` error on this URL `https://www.google.com/buzz/api/auth/OAuthPost` :(

What's wrong? Has anyone tried the Google Buzz API for Installed Applications??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that providing the `domain` parameter is essential even in Installed Applications, I set it to `anonymous` since I'm testing and the problem was solved :)

Sorry to bother you but I'm sure this will help others in the future ;)

Comment: Yeah, the parameter name is unfortunate.  The value of `domain` must be your OAuth consumer key.

Comment: Also, if you're using `anonymous` as your consumer key, you should probably send the `xoauth_displayname` parameter as well.  It makes for a much better user experience.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured that sending the `xoauth_displayname` will be better. I've also published my code here: http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/google-buzz-oauth-and-python/